# How to pass $ctrl value from one place to other component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using Angular JS (1.6) application. Inside my app I have components -

oprExternalInstructionsApp ->

oprScriptListPanel ->

I have `<opr-list>` component in my `oprScriptListPanel` templete file. I am passing `$ctrl.externalInstructionsFiltered` in `<opr-script-list-panel>`
Like `items="$ctrl.externalInstructionsFiltered"`
but I don’t see `{{$ctrl.externalInstructionsFiltered}}` is having any data inside my templete `oprScriptListPanel`.

My template code -

```
<opr-script-list-panel
    items="$ctrl.externalInstructionsFiltered"
    toolbar-buttons="$ctrl.toolbarButtons"
    selected-items="$ctrl.selectedInstructions"
    on-search="$ctrl.filterExternalInstructionsChanged(text)"
    on-double-click="$ctrl.edit(item)"
    item-actions="$ctrl.itemActions"
    item-tags="$ctrl.itemTags"></opr-script-list-panel>
```

in `<opr-script-list-panel` component I am passing `items` -

```
this.externalInstructionsFiltered = [{
            "id": "1",
            "displayName": "abc",
            "description": "aqaa",
            "timeout": "3000",
            "isEnabled": "false",
            "isReadOnly":"false",
            "stepId":"ExternalInterface",
            "version":"1",
            "artifactOrigin":"custom",
            "filterId":"qwq" ,
            "filterName":"sdsf",
            "Script": "abc",
            "active": true,
            "winner": true,
            "icon": "abc"
          }];
```

Component file for `opr-script-list-panel`

```
import './oprScriptListPanel.template.html';

var oprScriptListPanelComponent = {
  templateUrl: 'oprScriptListPanel.template.html',
  bindings: {
    toolbarButtons: "<?",
    selectedItems: "@?",
    onSearch:"&?",
    items:"=?",
    data:"=ngModel",
    oprListDeleteMode:"&?",
    onDoubleClick:"&?",
    itemActions:"&?",
    itemTags:"&?"
  }
};

export default oprScriptListPanelComponent;
```

Template file-

```
<div>
    <opr-toolbar
    buttons="$ctrl.toolbarButtons"
    selected-items="$ctrl.selectedInstructions"
    filter-placeholder="Filter instructions"
    on-search="$ctrl.filterExternalInstructionsChanged(text)"
    show-first-separator="true">
    </opr-toolbar>
  </div>

  <div class="empty-info"  ng-if="$ctrl.externalInstructionsFiltered && !$ctrl.externalInstructionsFiltered.length">
    <p ng-bind=":: 'opr.external.instructions.emptyList' | oprL10n"></p>
  </div>
  {{$ctrl.externalInstructionsFiltered}}
  {{$ctrl.selectedInstructions}}
```

I am not getting any data for `{{$ctrl.externalInstructionsFiltered}}`, But if I will print `{{$ctrl.toolbarButtons"}}` I am able to see some array. I checked module reference is correct. I am not getting any error.

Comment: Your question is very hard to follow. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Yes, Sure.I am not able to to pass $ctrl value from one template to other component..

Comment: @CosminAbabei updated my question please check..

Comment: I still find it hard to understand...